# How to move Review & Payments section below the Shipping section in magento 2

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment-methods, shipping-address, checkout-page, component

[image: Review and Payments Progress Bar]

How to move Review & Payments section below the Shipping section in checkout page
my requirement is to show both sections in one page ,one by one
by default review&payment section come after clicking next button ,any chance to show after shipping section directly....
any help?

Comment: Did you found any solution ??

Comment: Did you find any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

To move the Review & Payments section below the Shipping section in Magento 2, you will need to create a new layout file that updates the order of the sections on the checkout page. Here is a general outline of the steps you would need to take:

1. Create a new module in your Magento 2 installation. This can be done by creating a new directory in the app/code directory and adding the necessary files for a Magento 2 module.
2. In your new module, create a new layout file that updates the order of the sections on the checkout page. This can be done by creating a new checkout_index_index.xml file in the view/frontend/layout directory of your module.
3. In the new layout file, use the  element to move the Review & Payments section below the Shipping section. For example:

```python
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="checkout.root" destination="content" before="-"/>
        <move element="checkout.root.review" destination="checkout.root" after="checkout.root.shipping"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

4. Clear the cache and check your checkout page, the Review & Payments section should now be below the Shipping section.

**Note:** *These are the general steps and you may need to adjust the path and details according to your project's requirement.*